# how to call function of scala class from main method?

Tags: scala

i am learning as i could not install scala plugin in my laptop because its 32 bit so i am practising in command prompt. I have created below scala classes but i am not sure hot call function from main method.

```
class AccessTest
{
  def display():Unit= println("this is from accessTest")
}

Object Hello
{
val access  = new AccessTest();
access.display();
}
```

both classes are in com folder. i am not sure about creating package manually .
can somebody help me on this?

Comment: You got the correct way. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: i did not give any package for both classed i just created like 1. mkdir com 2. cd com 3. AccessTest.scala 4. Hello.scala

Comment: when i compile -> scalac Hello.scala i am getting Hello.scala:11: error: not found: type AccessTest
    val access = new AccessTest();
                     ^
one error found, might be because of package issue

Comment: why don't you put the AccessTest class as a companion class in Hello.scala? otherwise you need to compile the AccessTest class before you compile Hello.scala.

Comment: i have compiled AccessTest class before i compile Hello.scala may i know about companion , can u give some example?

Comment: just define the AccessTest below of Hello object in the same file Hello.scala.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing spell mistake while creating the object. You are giving `Object` instead of `object`. Here is an example:

```
scala> class AccessTest {
     |   def display():Unit= println("this is from accessTest")
     | }
defined class AccessTest

scala> object Hello extends  App{
     | val access  = new AccessTest();
     | access.display();
     | }
defined object Hello
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply Write a main method in object and call the main method using object name .(dot) main method with Array("")

```
scala>object MynewObj{
def main(args: Array[String]){
println("Hello World")
}
}

defined object MynewObj

scala> MynewObj.main(Array(""))
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

To call it from main method, you either need to extend App or define main method. And object of 'o' must be in small letter.

```
scala> class AccessTest{
     |   def display():Unit= println("this is from accessTest")
     | }
defined class AccessTest

scala> object Hello extends App{
     | val access  = new AccessTest();
     | access.display();
     | }
defined object Hello

scala> Hello.main(Array(""))
this is from accessTest

scala>
```